# How to make dynamic height of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I would like to create dynamic height of `UITableViewCell` depending tablecell content.

But i couldn't.

```
import UIKit


    class WorkItemCell: UITableViewCell{
        
        
        @IBOutlet weak var item_view: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var minimum_startday_label: CustomLabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var catchcopyLabel: CustomLabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var stationLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var paymentLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var limitLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var mainjobLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var companyLabel: UILabel!
        
        @IBOutlet weak var workstartdateLabel2: UILabel!
        
        @IBOutlet weak var fav_view: ImageWithView!
        @IBOutlet weak var img_seen_view: UIImageView!
        
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            
            //self.fav_view = ImageWithView.instance()
            
            self.fav_view.checkedImage = UIImage(named: "fav_on")
            self.fav_view.uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "fav_off")
            
            
        }
        
        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.catchcopyLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.catchcopyLabel.bounds)
            
        }
        
        
        private var _workdic: NSDictionary?
        var workdic: NSDictionary? {
            get {
                return _workdic
            }
            set(workdic) {
                _workdic = workdic
                if let workdic = workdic {
                    
                    let workplace = workdic["WorkPlace"] as? String
                    let companyname = workdic["CompanyName"] as? String
                    let jobname = workdic["JobName"] as? String
                    let payment = workdic["Payment"] as? String
                    let workstartdate = workdic["WorkStartDate"] as? String
                    let workdatetime = workdic["WorkDateTime"] as? String
                    let minimumday = workdic["MinimumWorkDay"] as? String
                    let applyenddate = workdic["ApplyEndDate"] as? String
                    let catchcopy = workdic["CatchCopy"] as? String
                    
                    
                    if notnullCheck(catchcopy){
                        //行間
                        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: catchcopy!)
                        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5
                        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail
                        attributedText.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))
                        self.catchcopyLabel.attributedText = attributedText
                    }
                    self.catchcopyLabel.sizeToFit()
                    
                    if let payment_constant = payment{
                        self.paymentLabel.text = payment_constant
                    }
                    
                    if notnullCheck(minimumday) && notnullCheck(workstartdate){
                        self.minimum_startday_label.text = minimumday!+" "+workstartdate!
                        
                    }else{
                        self.minimum_startday_label.text = ""
                    }
                    if let applyenddate_constant = applyenddate{
                        self.limitLabel.text = applyenddate_constant
                    }
                    
                    if let jobname_constant = jobname{
                        self.mainjobLabel.text = jobname_constant
                    }
                    
                    
                    if let workdatetime_constant = workdatetime{
                        self.workstartdateLabel2.text = workdatetime_constant
                    }
                    
                    
                    if let companyname_constant = companyname{
                        self.companyLabel.text = companyname_constant
                    }
                    
                    self.stationLabel.text = workplace
                    self.item_view.sizeToFit()
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        class func heightForRow(tableView: UITableView, workdic: NSDictionary?) -> CGFloat {
            struct Sizing {
                static var cell: WorkItemCell?
            }
            if Sizing.cell == nil {
                Sizing.cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WorkItemCell") as? WorkItemCell
            }
            if let cell = Sizing.cell {
                cell.frame.size.width = CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds)
                cell.workdic = workdic
                cell.setNeedsDisplay()
                cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                
                let size = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
                print(size)
                return size.height+1
            }
            return 0
        }
        
    }
```

Above code has item_view.
It has all label and image.
It is setted margin at 4 points(top,left,bottom,right),5px.

I use above cell for data list.
It has around 5000 counts.

Catch copy label is often setted 2 line sentence.
I want to change item_view height and cell height each catch_copy_label's height.

But I couldn't.
I always have gotten same height,26px.

```
(366.5, 26.0)
(366.5, 26.0)
```

What should i do?

I have add the part of view controller's source.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    
    
    if self.int_total == 0{
        return self.view.frame.size.height
    }else{
        if let workdic: AnyObject = workdata.safeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row){
            
            return WorkItemCell.heightForRow(self.workview, workdic: (workdic as! NSDictionary),base_height:170)
            
        }else{
            return 199
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 199
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    
    if self.int_total == 0{
        return 1
        
    }
    return self.workdata.count

}



/*
Cellに値を設定する.
*/
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    // Cellの.を取得する.
    if self.int_total > 0{
        
        

        let cell = workItemCell(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath, str_xib: "WorkItemCell")
        return cell
        
    }else{
        let nocell: NoCountCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NoCountCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NoCountCell
        nocell.conditionButton.addTarget(self, action: "onClickBack:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        
        //初期が終わったらfalse
        if self.init_loading{
            nocell.conditionButton.hidden = true
            nocell.messageLabel.hidden = true
        }else{
            nocell.conditionButton.hidden = true
            nocell.messageLabel.hidden = false
        }
        return nocell
    }
    
}
func workItemCell(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath,str_xib:String) ->WorkItemCell{
    let wcell: WorkItemCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(str_xib, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WorkItemCell
    wcell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    wcell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    updateCell(wcell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    
    return wcell
}

func updateCell(cell:UITableViewCell,atIndexPath:NSIndexPath){
    
}


func showWorkItem(wcell:WorkItemCell,workdic:NSDictionary){
    
    
    
    wcell.workdic = workdic
    
}
```

I have posted capture.
[image]

Comment: what is the console output for `print(size)` ?

Comment: I don't see where you set the content of size to calculate the height?

Comment: @ShebinKoshy Output is following.(284.5, 0.0)
(284.5, 0.0)
(284.5, 0.0)
(284.5, 0.0)
(284.5, 0.0)
(284.5, 0.0)
(284.5, 0.0)

Comment: @anhtu I have setted cell's height at xib.But i don't set item_view's height.

Answer (score 0):

This is in Objective C.Calculate the height of cell's content in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method add it in one array as

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)t heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[content_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.tblView.frame.size.width - PADDING * 3, 1000.0f)];
   NSLog(@"%f",textSize.height);
   [height_Array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", textSize.height]];
   return textSize.height;
}
```

Now in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method set the frame of title using height array as:-

```
 CGRect newFrame = txtTitle.frame;
 newFrame.size.height = [[height_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];                
 txtTitle.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: you should not add object in array because if you reload table then this method will call again and your objects will be double. so you have to remove all objects before reload table everytime. you can do same thing while you parse data. so you can use main array in which your actual data exist if you want.

Comment: 'heightForRow' method is called at heightForRowAtIndexPath.I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly got answer.
But i have calculated height manually.

I calculated the label's height at each time. 
This label has multi line.
Then I set height other height + the height which was calcuted.

```
class func heightForCatchCopy(tableView: UITableView, workdic: NSDictionary?) -> CGFloat {
    struct Sizing {
        static var cell: WorkItemCell?
    }
    if Sizing.cell == nil {
        Sizing.cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WorkItemCell") as? WorkItemCell
    }
    if let cell = Sizing.cell {
        cell.frame.size.width = CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds)
        cell.workdic = workdic

        let size = cell.catchcopyLabel.intrinsicContentSize()
        return size.height
    }
    return 0
}
```